# Building Minix 3.3 Errors

Tags: c, unix, minix

i installed minix 3.3 ,then i downloaded the source and tried to build followd this [link](http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:trackingcurrent) instructions.
i got an error building minix as follows:

```
*** Error code 1
Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/src/gnu/usr.bin/texinfo
*** Error code 1
Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/src/gnu/usr.bin/texinfo
*** Error code 1
Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/src/gnu/usr.bin
*** Error code 1
Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/src/gnu
*** Error code 1
Stop.
make: stopped in /usr/src
*** Error code 1
Stop. 
make: stopped in /usr/src
```

i found same problem discussed in this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/minix3/vNd00q5PdnA) ,i followd the instructions mentioned there:

```
#pkgin in gtexinfo

#cd /usr/src/gnu/usr.bin/texinfo

#makeinfo -I/usr/src/gnu/dist/texinfo/doc --no-split -o info-stnd.info /usr/src/gnu/dist/texinfo/doc/info-stnd.texi

#makeinfo -I/usr/src/gnu/dist/texinfo/doc --no-split -o info.info /usr/src/gnu/dist/texinfo/doc/info.texi

#makeinfo -I/usr/src/gnu/dist/texinfo/doc --no-split -o texinfo.info /usr/src/gnu/dist/texinfo/doc/texinfo.txi

#cd ../../..

#make -C gnu/usr.bin/texinfo all
```

at last command i recieve the following error

```
#make -c gnu/usr.bin/texinfo all
    create texinfo/info-stnd.info
unknown option: no-version-header
*** Error code 1
stop.
make:stopped in /usr/src/gnu/usr.bin/texinfo
```

is there is a way to build it without errors.